# Java Script variable in php file and use it in same file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

First of all, Sorry coz this question has been asked many times in SO.But I am not able to find it working with mine.That's why I am posting here.

I have below script at the end of the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                   position.coords.longitude);
 });
 </script>
```

I want to use that `var pos` at the top of that php file.

I have tried like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//this script at bottom
$(document).ready(function(){
var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                   position.coords.longitude);
 });
 </script>

<?php
//this part at the top of the file 
if (isset($_GET['coordinates'])) {
    echo $_GET['coordinates'];
}
//I have tried with $_POST['coordinates'] ..but still no Echo
?>
```

Can any one help me out ?

Comment: where you want to used "pos" variable in that files please specify.

Comment: You know that php is server side and javascript is client side.

Comment: You need to bind the values to an html element and then retrieved using  get or post method

Comment: @renishkhunt I have one php file and at the end of that file I have javascript.I want variable of that script at top.Is It possible ?

Comment: @KristerAndersson Yes, I know.

Comment: @shammon Can you tell me how can I do that ?

Comment: @shammon - What has that got to do with this question?

Comment: @Twix, bind this value to hidden input in javascript , LIKE 


    `"<input type='hidden' id='someId' value='"+pos+"'/>"`

Comment: @SHAZ Nope ..Not working ..It is just printin `"+pos+"`.

Comment: Use ajax instead of binding

Comment: @shammon I have no idea about ajax.I know very less about it.

Comment: just google that that thing